# Get latest record for each day for last n days using MS Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

```
CurrencyId  LeftCurrencyId RightCurrencyId    ExchangeRateAt            ExchangeRate 
 1             1             5                2013-06-27 00:51:00.000    39.0123 
 2             3             5                2013-06-26 01:54:00.000    40.0120 
 3             1             5                2013-06-26 00:51:00.000    49.0143 
 4             3             5                2013-06-25 14:51:00.000    33.3123 
 5             3             5                2013-06-25 06:51:00.000    32.0163
 6             1             5                2013-06-25 00:08:00.000    37.0123
```

I need latest record for each day for last n days based on combination of leftcurrencyid and rightcurrencyid.

Comment: And what have you tried? BTW, which SQL Server version?

Comment: And can you add what the output should look like? And some actual SQL with the table and data too

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos : it's 2008 R2

Answer (score 4):

Here's one option:

```
with TopPerDay as
(
  select *
    , DayRank = row_number() over (partition by LeftCurrencyId, RightCurrencyId, cast(ExchangeRateAt as date)
                                   order by ExchangeRateAt desc)
   from ExchangeRate
)
select CurrencyId,
  LeftCurrencyId,
  RightCurrencyId ,
  ExchangeRateDay = cast(ExchangeRateAt as date),
  ExchangeRateAt ,
  ExchangeRate
from TopPerDay
where DayRank = 1
order by LeftCurrencyId,
  RightCurrencyId,
  ExchangeRateDay
```

[SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/58ac0/7).

It groups by *LeftCurrencyId*, *RightCurrencyId*, and *ExchangeRateAt* day without the time component, then takes the latest record in the day for all those groups.

You don't mention whether you want N days back is from the present day or an unspecified date, but you can add this using a `WHERE` clause when selecting from the *ExchangeRate* table in the CTE definition.

Comment: You're welcome. If you find an answer helpful, please consider setting it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here are my two cents

```
Select ExchangeRateAt , * from Table1 where ExchangeRateAt in (Select max(ExchangeRateAt) from Table1 Group by  cast( ExchangeRateAt as Date))
Order by ExchangeRateAt
```

Answer (score 0):

Here `7` in the end is the last N days parameter (7 in this example)

```
with T1 as
(
select t.*,
   cast(floor(cast([ExchangeRateAt] as float)) as datetime) as DatePart,  
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
          PARTITION BY [LeftCurrencyId],
                       [RightCurrencyId],
                       cast(floor(cast([ExchangeRateAt] as float)) as datetime)
          ORDER BY [ExchangeRateAt] DESC
     ) RowNumber
from t
), T2 as 
(
  select *,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [LeftCurrencyId],
                                  [RightCurrencyId]
                     ORDER BY DatePart DESC
                    ) as RN  
  from T1 where RowNumber=1
) 

select [CurrencyId],
       [LeftCurrencyId],
       [RightCurrencyId],
       [ExchangeRateAt],
       [ExchangeRate],
       DatePart  
from T2 where RN<=7
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d9183/10)